# Which tools use this forum for realtime update?

Tags: ajax, synchronization, real-time, reverse-ajax

Anyone can explain to me how stackoverflow can push notification in real time ? For example if you upvote or downvote my question I'll see the update of the count vote in my browser instantly.

I didn't see any ajax request in the chrome console... Maybe they use socket.io or something like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about the site itself belong on the meta site

Comment: Okay thanks. Sorry for the mistake